# Rust can't use enum in const fn?

Tags: rust

This code wouldn't compile, why Rust don't even allow this? It's just simple enum variation test, is there any way to workaround?

```
#![feature(const_fn)]

struct Test {}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Copy, Clone)]
enum Vk {
    BLOCK,
    ITEM,
}

trait HasC {
    const d: Vk;
}

impl HasC for Test {
    const d: Vk = Vk::BLOCK;
}

const fn try_use_enum_in_const_fn<T: HasC>() -> bool {
    const a: Vk = Vk::BLOCK;
    T::d == a
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", try_use_enum_in_const_fn::<Test>());
}
```

It gets error

```
error[E0015]: calls in constant functions are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
  --> src/main.rs:21:5
   |
21 |     T::d == a
   |     ^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0015`.
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=%23!%5Bfeature(const_fn)%5D%0A%0Astruct%20Test%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(PartialEq%2C%20Eq%2C%20Copy%2C%20Clone)%5D%0Aenum%20Vk%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20BLOCK%2C%0A%20%20%20%20ITEM%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20HasC%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20d%3A%20Vk%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20HasC%20for%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20d%3A%20Vk%20%3D%20Vk%3A%3ABLOCK%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20fn%20try_use_enum_in_const_fn%3CT%3A%20HasC%3E()%20-%3E%20bool%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20a%3A%20Vk%20%3D%20Vk%3A%3ABLOCK%3B%0A%20%20%20%20T%3A%3Ad%20%3D%3D%20a%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20try_use_enum_in_const_fn%3A%3A%3CTest%3E())%3B%0A%7D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's just simple enum variation test

Not exactly. You're using `==` which desugars to an application of the `PartialEq` method `eq`. Since `const` trait methods aren't possible yet (and [the RFC for them hasn't even been accepted](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2632)), you can't mark that method as `const`, so `==` is unusable in `const` functions.

Well ... almost unusable. There are a few exceptions for primitive types. Replace your `T::d == a` with `2 == 2` and [everything compiles fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=86d0734b017334016b2d7a195c935b99). The reason is that equality between certain primitive types (including integers and floats) doesn't use the `PartialEq` trait but is implemented more intrinsically. This intrinsic implementation *can* be used in `const` functions.

---

The most idiomatic solution might be to use a `match` or `if let` to check an enum variant, but unfortunately, [`match` doesn't work in `const` functions yet either](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49146). If you're using nightly (and it appears you are) the feature flag `const_if_match` will enable it.

```
const fn try_use_enum_in_const_fn<T: HasC>() -> bool {
    if let Vk::BLOCK = T::d {
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ce4472a2795ac37dd60e7c3b3012ee27)

---

It's somewhat of a hack, but on stable currently, you can reduce an enum variant check to equality between primitive integer types and take advantage of the compiler magic mentioned above. When none of the enum variants have data attached to them, [they can be cast](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/enumerations.html#custom-discriminant-values-for-field-less-enumerations) to primitive integer types. The first variant is by default 0, then 1 etc., though this can be overridden. (Though I'm sure you're aware that what you're doing with traits here isn't stable yet - so this won't work entirely on stable).

```
const fn try_use_enum_in_const_fn<T: HasC>() -> bool {
    const a: Vk = Vk::BLOCK;
    (T::d as isize) == (a as isize)
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef1d8332f43b2d1daa998e757fd40b53)